# How to store data in multiple collection at same time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections

```
User - username, password, role, status
Renters - user_id, address, country, zip_code
Landlord - user_id, address, property, country, affiliation
```

Here when I am creating new renters I got (`username`, `password`, `role`, `status`, `address`, `country`, `zip_code`). So, I want to store this info in both collections (**User, Renters**) at the same time.

How we can do this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in version 4.0, MongoDB provides the ability to perform multi-document transactions against replica sets.

See more on [MongoDB Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)